Confused about this usage of "構えてしまいます"
The character called 瀧 suggested going to place at least once to do a preliminary inspection of the place. 耀 however points out that going again once has value... but then if something were to happen after they do it, it will be a huge hassle.
耀「勿論もう一回行くのはアリだけどな。ただ…またなんかあったら面倒だよな」
瀧「そうなんですよね…構えてしまいます」
Thus 瀧 adds "yes, you are right.. and finally 構えてしまいます
I'm unsure on how to take it here. I assume he's saying it like "I got carried away"? 構えて has a lot of usages but I've largely said it in the context of "paying attention to x"

When used in a physical sense, 構える means to be prepared or on guard against something by taking a certain posture or stance:

A fighter getting into their fighting stance
A batter settling into their batting position

It's also used to describe being psychologically prepared or on edge when anticipating a risky or challenging situation. Here, 瀧 is saying that he cannot go there again without being mentally prepared for some potential risks.
